# New class for element on click and reset classes for other elements

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

All my `<p>`s have a class "A". I want to change the class of a `<p>` when it's clicked to class "B" and reset all others to class "A".
Easy to change the `<p>`s to class "B", but completely stuck with reverting the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('p').click(function() {
    $('p').removeClass('B').addClass('A'); // revert all 'p's to 'A'
    $(this).removeClass('A').addClass('B'); // 'this' refers to the clicked object
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p2Qc9/1/)

Comment: Haha, great! Easier, than everything I tried :). Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know also how to remove the color if you click again on same element? Thanks